# Want to make the content appear in-between tabs

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Following is the bootstrap code. I want the result to be appear near the clicked tab instead of at the end. For Example - if someone clicks on the "Home" appearing in first row, then its content should be displayed after first row of tabs but not at the end. Please let me know if you can help and if any clarification needed.

You can also find this code on codepen [here](https://codepen.io/mutualdesigns/pen/pbGjbX)

```
<div>

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#1" aria-controls="1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#2" aria-controls="2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#3" aria-controls="3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#4" aria-controls="4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#5" aria-controls="5" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#6" aria-controls="6" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#7" aria-controls="7" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#8" aria-controls="8" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="1">1</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="2">2</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="3">3</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="4">4</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="5">5</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="6">6</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="7">7</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="8">8</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply placing a `.nav` followed by `.tab-content` will work on v3, out of the box, even for consecutive pairs:

```
<ul class="nav">
 ... tab controls group 1
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
   ... tab panels group 1
</div>
<div class="container">

<ul class="nav">
 ... tab controls group 2
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
   ... tab panels group 2
</div>
```

See full example here:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#1" aria-controls="1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="active">Home</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#2" aria-controls="2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#3" aria-controls="3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#4" aria-controls="4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="1">1</div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="2">2</div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="3">3</div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="4">4</div>
</div>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#5" aria-controls="5" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="active">Home</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#6" aria-controls="6" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#7" aria-controls="7" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#8" aria-controls="8" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="5">5</div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="6">6</div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="7">7</div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="8">8</div>
</div>
```

---

However, having multiple tab containers on the same page is not currently supported in v4. There's [a support ticket](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/27221) for it.

Comment: that code is being come by a loop so I don't think it would be good to break it in two listing of tabs. Also, I think it won't compatible for responsiveness as on mobile one row (4 links) would be converted into 4 rows and we want to display the content underneath each tab link. Makes sense?

Comment: You changed the markup from the original one posted. If you want two tab groups, like in the codepen, you don't have an alternative. You need to split the current `.tab-content` into two and display each after its own group of `.nav` controls. You can do it in Javascript, after you get it from the server, but that's what needs to be in the rendered HTML by the browser in order to display content of first 4 tabs after first group of 4 buttons and last tabs after next group.